# Regex quantifier for repeat sequence

Tags: php, regex

This is $input:

```
The random 3x3 matrix is: 
0.5673 -0.3193 0.7516 
0.4423 0.6708 -0.6121 
-0.9798 0.0217 -0.1712 
Row 2 has the minimum sum of -1.1293
```

I want to get that 9 elements, row number and minimum sum.
This is pattern:

```
$pattern = '/[^\A]+(-?[01]\.\d{4})[^\Z]+Row (\d) has the minimum sum of (-?\d+\.\d{4})\Z/'
```

But I see it failed to return 9 elements, like:

preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches)

var_dump($matches)

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(141) "The random 3x3 matrix is:<br>0.5673 -0.3193 0.7516<br>0.4423 0.6708 -0.6121<br>-0.9798 0.0217 -0.1712<br>Row 2 has the minimum sum of -1.1293"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "0.1712"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "-1.1293"
  }
}
```

How to fix $pattern to get 9 elements separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex using alternation in `preg_match_all`:

```
/(?:Row (\d+) has the minimum sum of )?(-?\d+\.\d+)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SU40ka/2)

Note that non capturing group `(?:...)` is optional allowing us to match numbers from upper lines as well.